# Is jQuery considered a language?

Tags: jquery

I was just wondering if jQuery can be considered as a language, since it has its own syntax. I can't say it's a library, because most other languages are made through a library of another language. For example, PHP is written in C and PHP functions call functions made in C.

Just wanted to hear ideas and insights from all of you.

Comment: That's not an accurate definition of a library.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It doesn't have its own syntax, it's simply plain JavaScript.

They implement a [*fluent interface* pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), that basically allows you to chain function calls, e.g.:

```
$(argument).method1().method2(); // etc...
```

`$` is allowed to be used as an Identifier, that's why many libraries use it, not just jQuery.

In the above example, the `$` identifier is in the context of a *call expression*, `$(arguments)` is just similar to `myFunction(argument)`, that function call returns an object, that contains other properties that are by itself methods, that can be called subsequently as a *"chain"*.

An example of a language built on top JavaScript (something slightly similar to your *C => PHP* example) would be [*CoffeeScript*](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/).

Comment: So you are basically saying that jQuery is simply a function in javascript?

Comment: @andsien jQuery is a collection of JavaScript functions.

Answer (score 5):

It's a javascript library.  So i'd say no.  Javascript is the language.

Comment: +1 JQuery doesn't add any syntax that wasn't already valid JavaScript. It has design patterns and conventions, but it's still just a library.

Answer (score 5):

No, jQuery is a JavaScript library.  It doesn't have its own syntax, but rather (as Jason said) a set of conventions for using JavaScript syntax.

PHP is a language with a runtime written in C.  PHP code is obviously not C code.

Comment: That's a pretty good comparison, although it starts to fall apart when you realise that PHP is a much thicker layer, with a separate syntax, language parser, and so on, while jQuery is a light layer that runs within the parent language.

Comment: @Delan, it's not my comparison.  I'm critiquing and clarifying the OP's analogy.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will need interpreter to call something a language. jQuery doesn't have any special interpreter... its using JS's

Answer (score 1):

jQuery, MooTools, Dojo, Prototype and other libraries can't considered as a language. But one can know how to use jQuery well and don't know how to use JavaScript properly.

Comment: My experience suggests the opposite.  People who don't know JavaScript tend to have serious gaps in their practical ability to use jQuery.

Comment: @Matthew, how would you define, "know JavaScript" and what do you see lacking in their practical ability to use jQuery?

Comment: "know JavaScript" - have a comprehensive (not complete) understanding of the language.  There are many examples; one that springs to mind is not understanding how JavaScript allows anonymous functions (closures) to be passed around and called asynchronously.  This results in people using `jQuery.ajax` incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have its own syntax. It exposes its own methods and properties. Just like anything else you can write in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery really doesn't have its own syntax - it uses the JavaScript syntax and language. So technically, no. However, it can drastically change the way you use JavaScript to work with HTML elements using client-side scripting, so it almost seems like its own language.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is basically a javascript having some user-friendly ways to use javascript with third party controls already made on it. These controls are generic functionality needed in common development. It has great support with great user interface. so in 4 or 5 steps you can integrate controls in your application.

http://jquery.com/ is a official site which has all you questions answered.

There is one know issue related to it is that jQuery many times conflict with Prototype.js (basic javascript file). User have to handle this conflict with a couple of line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt it a case of Minilanguaje?

> The domain-specific little language is an extremely powerful design idea. It allows you to define your own higher-level language to specify the appropriate methods, rules, and algorithms for the task at hand, reducing global complexity relative to a design that uses hardwired lower-level code for the same ends. You can get to a minilanguage design in at least three ways, two of them good and one of them dangerous.[1](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/minilanguageschapter.html)

In my thought, it is a language one level up from pure javascript whenever it is not a precompiled nor interpreted language.

Comment: Whenever JavaScript is an interpreted languaje, JQuery runs over it and inherits the condition of interpreted languaje.